# Finite time blow-up for solutions of a quasi-parabolic system

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I am reading a book about the Harmonic Map flow and in the proof of the existence of solution the author states something I am not totally familiar with. Let me recall the statement of the theorem.

> Let $(M, g)$ and $(N, h) \subset \mathbb R^L$ be two compact Riemannian manifold without boundaries. Then for $u_0 \in C^\infty(M, N)$ there exists a maximal $T \in (0,+\infty]$ such that
> \begin{cases}
> \partial_t u - \Delta_gu = A(u)(\nabla u, \nabla u) & \text{in } M \times (0,+\infty)\\
> u|_{t = 0} = u_0
> \end{cases}
> admits a unique, smooth solution $u \in C^\infty(M\times [0,T), N)$. Moreover, if $T < \infty$, then
> $$\lim_{t \to T} \|\nabla u(\cdot, t)\|_{L^\infty} = \infty.$$

Where $A(u)(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the second fundamental form.

My question is about last part of the statement, when $T< \infty$. The author just claims this fact "by *parabolic regularity* as this equation is a quasi-linear parabolic system" [sic]. I have never seen nor used such "parabolic regularity" argument so I was wondering if one of you could tell me more about it, or give me a reference with the proof ?

Comment: The argument would just be that if this norm does not blow up, you can propagate the solution further, like in ODE theory. You would show, e.g. that (1) if you have smooth initial data, you have short-time existence (usually pretty easy to show) and (2) if you have a solution with this Lipschitz bound on [0, T), it is actually smooth up to T (this is the regularity part). For (2), since you know the RHS is bounded, you get that $u$ is $C^{1, \alpha}$ from Schauder estimates, and then you can bootstrap this.